# Web Service - "Current Connections" performance counter

Tags: performancecounter, stress-testing

Recently I start to work with VSTS and I made some test scripts to run against an website.
The scripts consists basically of a synchronous WebService request.

I ran this script with 2000 users and checked the Current Connections Performance Counter but it was never higher than 17.
The amount of Tests Running is always near 150 and since the test only contains one WebService request I thought the Current Connections would be similar to this number.

Can someone explain me what the Current Connections counter really means since it doesn't seems be the number of requests been processed at a time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the WebTest Connection Model and WebTest Connection Pool Size from the properties of your Run Settings in the load test. These settings have a lot to do with connection re-use to the server.

Current connections records the number of connections open, whether currently active or not.
[This article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/af36e903-75c3-4a4c-ae47-8663f8543b0c.mspx?mfr=true) describes the counter in more depth.

" These counters can exaggerate the number of simultaneous connections because, at any given moment, some entries may not have been deleted even though the connections on which they are based have been closed. "

Comment: I am using the Connection per User model and the Current Connection works like a charm when I am doing HTTP requests but when I am using a WebService the number of Current connection is several times lower than it should be in theory. 
Using HTTP requests, I got 1 or 2 current connections per user I am simulating, but when I am testing WebServices, even with 2000 users this counter wont hit more than 50. According to the article, I thought the counter would be always higher than the real number of connections, but that is not the case when we are testing webservices, any clue why this happens?

Comment: I don't know enough about the lifecycle of IIS connections with webservices. Perhaps the connection is closed immediately following the call, allowing the counter to incorrectly collect the connection information. Sorry I cannot be of more help.